# Floating divs next to each other when printing webpage

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a webpage which displays pairs of items as such

```
[ item 1 ] [ item 2 ]
[ item 3 ] [ item 4 ]
[ item 5 ] [ item 6 ]
[ item 7 ] [ item 8 ]
```

Fine in the browser, but I want them to display like this on a *printed* page. When pressing ctrl+p, the preview shows them all listed one after another.

```
[ item 1 ] 
[ item 2 ] 
[ item 3 ] 
[ item 4 ] 
etc...
```

Where do I start with this? My google fu on the subject is weak :(

Answer (score 3):

Make use of media-queries:

**Use them inline:**

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='print' href='filepath.css'/>
```

**Use them in a combined css-file.**

```
@media print {
    /* CSS Styling for the print page */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Printing a webpage won't display `float` or `display: inline-block;` correctly. Using `display: table-cell` will make your block-level elements behave more like `<td>` elements. Also, if you have to contain a row of cells, you can logically use `display: table-row` to behave like a `<tr>` element.

Within your stylesheet, try something like:

```
@media print {
    .item-class {
         display: table-cell;
         width: 50%;
    }
}
```

**Tip**: Use Chrome dev tools' "Overrides" tab then "Emulate CSS media" and change to "print".

**Note**: You can also use widths in inches, but since different browsers may have varying margins while printing, don't expect the same total width to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS style sheet, set up special CSS rules for printing:

```
@media print {
    /* CSS rules for printing here */
}
```